# PHP arrays to Javascript using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to programm my own first webapplication. The datatraffic between the server and the clients should  established by using AJAX. First I tried to transfer a userinput (HTML-form) from the client side to the server side with this JS-snippet:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({            
        url : "ajax.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : $("#nodes").serialize(),
        dataType: "text",
        cache : false,
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
            $("#ajaxrequest").html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nERROR: "+ err);
        }
    });
});
```

It worked... But now I want to overhand three different data (PHP-)arrays from my server to the client side with:

```
<?php

echo json_encode($currentdata);
echo json_encode($maxmindata);
echo json_encode($chartdata);
```

I was wondering that the arrays are shown in the console.log, until I regonized `data: $("#nodes").serialize(),` contains all transfered data. Certainly I need to extract all three arrays in different variables in my JS file.

I tried something like

```
success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
            current = data.currentdata;
}
```

of course it didnt work...

this is the output of the console:

```
> {"max":{"temperature":"21.14","humidity":"39.96","pressure":"1022.2"},"min":{"temperature":"21.08","humidity":"38.72","pressure":"1022.0"}}{"current":{"ID":"755","temperature":"21.43","humidity":"40.09","pressure":"1022.8","voltage":"3.337","datetime":"2017-04-18
> 20:46:31"}}[{"ID":"570","nodeId":"Node1","humidity":"38.83","temperature":"21.08","pressure":"1022.2","voltage":"3.323","datetime":"2017-04-18
> 20:00:02"},{"ID":"571","nodeId":"Node1","humidity":"38.72","temperature":"21.08","pressure":"1022.1","voltage":"3.321","datetime":"2017-04-18
> 20:00:17"},{"ID":"572","nodeId":"Node1","humidity":"38.84","temperature":"21.1","pressure":"1022.1","voltage":"3.321","datetime":"2017-04-18
> 20:00:32"},
```

If you dont get what I want to ask: How can I assign the different PHP-arrays to different JS-variables? Do I need to programm another $.ajax ?

Comment: Create array of arrays.

Comment: Well, this comment helped nothing.

Comment: You're sending 3 array object one after the other. Example: on your console you have `..}}[{..`. Create a new array containing your 3 arrays and return this one.

Comment: Niclas, if @u_mulder's comment did not help, the only thing that will help is research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if comment didn't help, here's an answer.

Create array with all your values:

```
<?php
$result_array = array(
    'current_data' => $currentdata,
    'max_min_data' => $maxmindata,
    'chart_data' => $chartdata,
);

echo json_encode($result_array);
```

Also modify your js:

```
$.ajax({            
    url : "ajax.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : $("#nodes").serialize(),
    // set dataType as `json`, this will create json object from response automatically
    dataType: "json",   
    cache : false,
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
        console.log( data.current_data );   // key is the same as in php array
        //$("#ajaxrequest").html(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nERROR: "+ err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! 
@AndreiGheorghiu I'm learning JS and PHP since two weeks. I spend nearly a day with this problem, so please don't blame me for my unknowledge!

Comment: Ok, @NiclasResse. I'll take the blame for it. Joke aside, when someone tells you what to do you don't reply with "this helped nothing". The least you can do is thank and (re)search.

Comment: Yep, @AndreiGheorghiu I agree with you, but if you spend many time for some stupid issues and no solution is in sight, it should be allowed to ask a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: With all due respect, @Niclas, you are quite wrong. [so] is dedicated to programmers. By replying with "this helped nothing" when suggested "use an array of arrays", you simply do not qualify. Congratulations for your will to learn, keep it up and you will soon ask quality questions and you'll be able to understand suggestions and answers, when provided.